# how to add something like onhashchange, but for href

Tags: javascript, html

the `onhashchange` is great for when the link is "#somewhere", but would like something for `location.href` instead of merely `location.hash`

if I can handle the request through Ajax, then will reload part of the page.  otherwise will follow link.

would like url in location at top of page to reflect the clicked link.

is this possible?

if site is www.example.com/sub1/page1

if user clicks on www.example.com/sub1/page2, I can handle this in Ajax.  I will redraw part of the page.  I wish the location bar at the top of the page to say www.example.com/sub1/page2

if the user clicks on www.example.com/sub1/page3, I cannot handle it in Ajax.  I wish to href to behave as normal.

so I need to grab changes to `location.href` and allow or disallow browser to behave in default manner

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: @PraveenKumar - explained more.  does this help?

Comment: Search google for the "history api". I believe it does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: unfortunately you can't change `location.href` without refreshing the page. the solution would be to do something like `www.example.com/sub1/page1#/sub1/page3` and then on page load check if  your `location.pathname` matches the `location.hash` and if not, do some manipulations